# Running a do loop

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am attempting to build a loop to check for files in a folder then run a loop if files exist in the folder and keep running the loop until no more files are left, but I am running into the token error, "syntax error near unexpected token `do'. Here is the script I am trying to run.

```
files=/satellite/MSGVIS6/* 
if [ "${#files[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then
do
    mcenv << 'EOF'
    imgcopy.k MSGVI6D MSGVI6I BAND=1 SIZE=SAME
    imgremap.k MSGVI6I MSGVI6I.2 SIZE=ALL PRO=MERC RES=3.00
    imgcha.k MSGVI6I.2 STYPE=GVAR
    imgdel.k MSGVI6I.1
    exit
    EOF
    find /satellite/awips/ -type f -name 'AREA6022*' -exec mv '{}' /awips2/edex/data/manual/ \;
    rm -rf "$files"
    done

else
echo ''
echo "No files downloaded. New area files will not be created."
fi 

exit 0
```

Any thoughts on what I may be writing incorrectly?

Comment: Leave the `do` out and put a semicolon between `if [ "${#files[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then` or put the `then` onto the next line.

Comment: @Videonauth   I am looking for it to keep running until there are no more files left in the folder. Will it keep doing that without the "do loop" in place?

Comment: The dash shell doesn't support arrays. Are you sure that's what you want to use?

Comment: @muru Sorry, that was a mistake on my side. I am removing dash.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming bash, in a simple variable assignment, globbing is not performed:

```
$ a=*
$ echo "$a"
*
```

To get an array, you need to use parentheses:

```
a=(*)
```

For example, in `/usr`:

```
$ a=(*)
$ echo "$a" "${a[@]}"
bin bin include lib lib32 lib64 local sbin share src
```

So, your first line should actually read:

```
files=(/satellite/MSGVIS6/*)
```

To expand to all elements in an array `a`, use `"${a[@]}"`:

```
rm -rf "${files[@]}"
```

Other notes:

- You can use `mv -t` to make the `find` more efficient with `{} +`:

  ```
  find /satellite/awips/ -type f -name 'AREA6022*' -exec mv -t /awips2/edex/data/manual/ {} +
  ```
- Just use `echo` instead of `echo ''`:

  ```
  echo
  echo "No files downloaded. New area files will not be created."
  ```
- The `exit 0` is pointless.

Comment: I was actually using a shell script instead of bash. Will the shell script not work in this case?

Comment: Your shell script is run using some shell. I'm assuming you're using bash (Bourne Again *Shell*) for your shell script. If not, which shell are you using?

Comment: The shebang was run as shell... "#!/bin/sh"

Comment: On Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is dash, which, as I already said, doesn't support arrays.